# Edit status(and other fields) in fogbugz list view

Tags: fogbugz

We're evaluating the 45 demo of fogbugz. Thus far I like it, but there are some obvious things I'm missing.

What boggles me the most is how I can easely alter fields in the list view. I would like to open the detail screen as little as possible. It seems to be possible with the estimation column, why isn't it possible with all the other fields (like project, priority, status etc.?).

Comment: Hmm... I just voted to close as NPR... but now I'm not entirely sure. It's to do with a programming-related application, certainly. Hmm. Would like a "withdraw vote to close" button :)

Comment: He, to be honoust, I was doubting myself 'caus it is a bit borderline. But as I can't find my way in the fogbugz help forum itself I hoped SO would help me out.
If closed I understand ;)

Comment: Doesn't seem to get much love anyways it seems :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for can not be done in FogBugz 6.  You have to open up the case in order to edit most of the fields.  Why they made exceptions for time estimates, I don't know.

Comment: I have the same minor frustration.  I will just have to figure out how to make email cases route to the right people, projects, etc.  My typical scenario is to email myself/FB with some case information, then I have to go edit them all later in a batch and doing that for each one is tedious.  I want to just make changes on the list  view in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The rationale here was as a feature to accompany quick case entry. (That's the "Add Case" link at the bottom of each group or at the bottom of the grid.)

The thinking was that it'd be neat to be able to add cases quickly and then burn through the list, estimating them quickly.  We didn't really expand our thinking to include moving cases around or changing things like releases/milestones, etc.

This is something we'd like to offer in the future for many more fields, and one of those weird situations where adding a small, specific feature can sometimes make the fact that the larger, general implementation of that feature isn't there yet.

Comment: I already had the idea that something along those lines was what was going on.
By adding this feature to those fields users (at least my colleagues and me) start to expect this feature for other fields too. Does fogbugz have a uservoice?

Comment: Also: great that you are reacting to a stackoverflow post that isn't directly related to fog creek :)

Comment: For now, you can give direct feedback via email, phone, etc.  If you want others to see your feedback, the forum works, or stackoverflow,  though you risk getting a question closed. There's no feature voting as of yet, because we don't really have the ability to react to the input at this point. Expect this to change in the future. Once we get 7 out the door and see what's left, we'll likely take some serious steps to make aggregating feedback better.

Comment: I would also like the feature of being able to change the priority, assignment, project, version (for fix), etc.  (The ones with dropdown choices mostly.  )  I don't need to free-form,  just be able to move stuff around.

Answer (score 0):

FogBugz 6 isn't big on customisation.  You can edit the categories and statuses in the database tables directly (though you need to edit the "internal" project and click OK for the cache to be refreshed.

FogBugz 7 is coming out this year hopefully, and may well address many of these issues.

Comment: I think I miscomunicated. I don't want to change the categories, I want to change the entry for a specific bug without going to the detail screen.
For example, I want to change the priority of a bug from 4 to 3 but don't want to select the tick box, go to edit, set the field, press save.

Comment: FogBugz 7 is in limited beta right now, and we're accepting signups for new beta candidates. We'll look to release as soon as we're relatively certain we won't be releasing any glaring bugs out into the wild.